# Missing doc in non-user namespaces in Clojure 1.5

Tags: clojure, clojure-repl

What should I do to get `doc` available again?

```
brew install --devel leiningen
lein new app yeehaw
cd yeehaw
; edit project.clj and replace "1.4.0" with 1.5.0-RC1"
lein repl
yeehaw.core=> (doc map)
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: doc
in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:1)
```

This change comes from [CLJ-1085](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1085) and this [associated source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/commit/728972b026a323fc941a5d560b81d37453dc6cad).

Note that `doc` and the usual REPL functionality is still available in the `user` namespace, but it would be nice to have it at my fingertips in my app's namespace, at least while in the REPL.

Comment: Note: `brew install leiningen` works great now; no need for `--devel`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Get `doc` into current namespace:

```
(clojure.core/use '[clojure.repl :only (doc)])
```

And after that try `doc` again.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to help from clojure IRC, here are some options:

- use `clojure.repl/doc` instead of `doc`
- use `(apply require clojure.main/repl-requires)` to bring `doc` and other REPL functionality into a new namespace.